# Help with the inequality $a+{k}r\leq c+\sqrt{k}s$

Tags: inequality, rearrangement-inequality

Let $k\geq 0$. I want to find an upper bound for $k$ given that
$$a+{k}r\leq c+\sqrt{k}s$$
with $a,c,r,s$ any real constants.

My attempt was to write
$$(kr-\sqrt{k}s)^2\leq (c-a)^2$$
but can't go any further.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If $x=\sqrt{k}$ then you have to solve:

$$ rx^2 -sx +a-c \leq 0$$

If $x_1\leq x_2$ are solutions to the corresponding quadratic equation then we have:

- If $r>0$ then $x\in [x_1,x_2]\cap [0,\infty)$

> So if $x_2\geq 0$ then $k_{\max} =x_2^2$ else it does not exists.

- If $r<0$ then $x\in \Big((-\infty, x_1]\cup [x_2,\infty)\Big) \cap [0,\infty)$

> Maximal value for $k$ does not exists.

Comment: Thank you @nonuser ! One doubt: The bound is independent of $k$? I'm looking for the upper bound be in terms of $r, s, a$ and $c$.

Comment: Do not understand what are you asking. Calculate $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms f $r,s, a$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

For now, pretend that the ≤ sign is an = sign.  Then:

$$a+{k}r = c+\sqrt{k}s$$
$$a+kr-c = \sqrt{k}s$$
$$(a+kr-c)^2 = ks^2$$
$$a^2 + akr - ac + akr + k^2r^2 - ckr - ac - ckr + c^2 = ks^2$$
$$a^2 + 2akr - 2ac + k^2r^2 - 2ckr + c^2 - ks^2 = 0$$
$$r^2k^2 + (2ar - 2cr - s^2)k + (a^2 - 2ac + c^2) = 0$$

This gives you a quadratic in terms of $k$.

Recall that for a parabola expressed as $y = Ax^2 + Bx + C$, the vertex is at $x = \frac{-B}{2A}$ (and $y = \frac{4AC-B^2}{4A}$).  This is a maximum if $A < 0$, or a minimum if $A > 0$.